# how to make a search scope as default item displayed in searchbox dropdown

Tags: search-scope

How to make a search scope as default item displayed in searchbox dropdownsplayed in searchbox dropdown?

I have dropdown box placed next to Logo and this currently shows scope to search people . Other options are All sites, xyz site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to "Site Settings" in Site Collection Administration section
2. Click on "Search Settings"
3. Click on "Display Groups"
4. Click on "Search Drop Down"
5. Configure as Required and save settings

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I wasn't able to use this setting because I didn't have enough permission. I was only able to view the search scope setting and not able to make any change. Sorted out now with help of our Admin here.